# Express JS subdomain static content

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a API written in Node JS Express JS. I used [apidocjs.com](http://apidocjs.com/) to generate the static content. The problem i am having is i want the docs file to be under a subdomain [docs.example.com](http://docs.example.com) or [api.example.com/docs](http://api.example.com/docs) if that is the best practice?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/docs/api'));

app.use('/v1', subdomain('api', require('./controller/api_v1')(stormpath, log)));
app.use(subdomain('docs', require('./controller/docs')(stormpath, log)));

app.use(require('./controller/index')(stormpath, log));
```

This works if i change the index.html in docs/api to start.html.
So the last problem is how to stop express JS to start the index.html if i do not want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did it :)

Here is how. I used this lib to handel subdomain [express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain)

```
"APP.JS"
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/docs/api', {
    index: false,
    redirect: false
}));

app.use(subdomain('docs', require('./controller/docs')(log)));

"docs/api"
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/../docs/api/index.html'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`http://api.example.com/docs` is easily confused for an API resource called `docs`.

`http://docs.example.com/` avoids that ambiguity so it is probably a better choice.

Comment: I think that is a good way to do it. But how in express can i set subdomain and have a static path to apidocs?

Comment: @KristerJohansson I wouldn't do it with express, if it's all static. my 2c.

Comment: @KevinB How would you do it? Second server?

Comment: nginx or apache. have nginx listen on port 80/443, then reverse proxy that to my node server. If i have static assets, nginx serves them directly, whether it be on the same domain as the node app or a different one/sub domain.